# Replacing text with alphabet position (JavaScript)

Tags: arrays, string, loops, sorting

So I stored the alphabet in an array and split it, then I create a for loop for both the array(alphabet) and the (text).
In the (text) for loop I then checked if any value in (alphabet) was equal to any value in (text) if so then the output would return the index of the value in (alphabet)
Please tell me where I went wrong?

````
  var alpha = ["abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"];
  var spacedAlpha = alpha.split("")
  for (let i = 0;i < spacedAlpha.length;i++){

  for (let j = 0;j < text.length;j++){
text[j] == spacedAlpha[i] ? spacedAlpha.indexOf([i])
  }
 }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be easier to use :

```
'MyString'.charCodeAt(0)
```

Where the zero indicates the position in the String.
so if you loop through the string. it would return the character values for your string.

```
const myTestString = "MyString";
let ordinals = [];
for (let i = 0; i < myTestString.length; i++){
   ordidnals.push(myTestString.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

This puts your character-codes (Ordinals) in an array.